# How to fill UITableView with datas I'm receiving on ViewDidLoad?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am trying getting some datas with Alamofire and trying to put some of these datas into an array

```
class BaseFormViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let colorPalette = VOCColorPaletteManager()
let form = GetEmployeeCompositionApp()

let baseUrl = url
let parameters = parameters
var jsonData : EmployeeCompositionApp?

var separators : [Separator]?

// ------ IBOutlets ------

@IBOutlet weak var formTableView: UITableView!

/***   TableView   ***/
var xibCell = "BaseFormCell"
var reuseIdentifier = "BaseFormCell"



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = colorPalette.clearGrayColorObject()
    self.formTableView.delegate = self
    self.formTableView.dataSource = self
    self.formTableView.register(UINib(nibName: xibCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    requestAllForms()

}
```

this  `requestAllForms()` in ViewDidLoad is the method I use to get those datas

```
 func requestAllForms() {

        /*****    Petición a API    *****/

    Alamofire.request(baseUrl,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print("Error en petición a Alamofire:\n \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                return
            }
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] else {
                print("No se ha podido extraer un archivo JSON")
                if let error = response.result.error {
                    print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }

            /******    Parseado de JSON    *****/
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let rawData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
                let objectData = try decoder.decode(EmployeeCompositionApp.self, from: rawData)
                self.jsonData = objectData

            /*****    Metiendo datos en los arrays correspondientes    *****/

                for item in objectData.data.elements.separators {

                    self.separators?.append(item)

                }
                self.formTableView.reloadData()


            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \n", error)
            }

    }

}
```

But when I try to access the ViewController it crashes, I think it's because there's nothing in the array yet

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (separators?.count)!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BaseFormCell

    for item in (jsonData?.data.elements.separators)! {


        separators.append(item)
        cell.idLabel.text = item.separatorId
        cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
        cell.typeLabel.text = item.separatorType
        let separatorsID = item.separatorId
        cell.idLabel.text = separatorsID
        print("separators id: \(separatorsID)")
        let separatorsName = item.name
        cell.idLabel.text = separatorsName

        let separatorType = item.separatorType
        cell.idLabel.text = separatorType
    }



    return cell
}
```

When it crashes on console there's only `(lldb)`

and Xcode gives the error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x103216bdc)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there a better way to use the objects I get from the Json than putting them into an array inside the closure?

Thanks

Comment: "ViewController it crashes" Is there a message in console when this happens? Because usually it gives hints/reason why.

Comment: Where app crashes? What's log error message?

Comment: Yes I updated my first message

Comment: Put an `Exception` breakpoint and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your separators is never initialized when the numberOfRowsInSection is called.

Your separators property actually never gets initialized in your code.
The separators gets appended in your alamofire closure which is async. BUT, your separators is never initialized yet, so it will do nothing.

```
var separators : [Separator]? 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (separators?.count)! // Force unwrapping nil will cause crash
    return separators?.count ?? 0 // Safely unwrap like so.. Default 0 if separators is nil
}

// Alamofire closure
for item in objectData.data.elements.separators {
  self.separators?.append(item) // Appending to uninitialized array
}
```

Better yet, don't have separators as optional. You might have to fix your optional chaining errors.

```
var separators = [Separator]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return separators.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put check in numberOfRowsInSection as follows:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if separators != nil{
    return (separators?.count)!
   }
return 0
}
```

Your app is getting crashed because there might be scenarios where seaports array having no values and you are trying to populate it with nil array.